# "<function status.<locals>.uptimed at 0x000001C35A56FE20>", What is this?

Tags: python, discord.py

While I was coding my discord bot using disnake, when i use /status, instead of showing all information needed, the uptime gets this: `<function status.<locals>.uptimed at 0x000001C35A56FE20>` what's happening, and how to solve it?

Code:

````py
@bot.slash_command(description="Mostra a latência do bot", pass_context=True)
async def status(self, interaction: disnake.CommandInteraction):
    await interaction.response.defer()
    def uptimed():
        pass
        current_time = time.time()
        difference = int(round(current_time - start_time))
        text = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=difference))
        text.replace(" years", "Y")
        text.replace(" year", "Y")
        text.replace(" months", "M")
        text.replace(" month", "M")
        text.replace(" days", "d")
        text.replace(" day", "d")
        print(uptimed)
    
    before = time.monotonic()
    carregando = disnake.Embed(
        description="⏳ - Carregando...",
        color=0x00ffff
    )
    await interaction.edit_original_message(embed=carregando)
    ping = (time.monotonic() - before) * 1000
    Embed_De_Ping = disnake.Embed(
        title="Status:",
        description=f">  - Ping da Websocket: **{round(bot.latency * 1000)}**ms \n >  - Ping da Client: **{int(ping)}**ms \n>  - Uptime: **{uptimed}**",
        color=0x2f3136)
    await interaction.edit_original_message(embed=Embed_De_Ping)```
````

Comment: In your own words, exactly what do you expect `print(uptimed)` to do, and why? I see multiple issues in this code. There are at least two things wrong with that line of code, one of which is also wrong in another line (which is the actual cause of the reported problem). On top of which, every `text.replace` line does not actually accomplish anything. I really think it would be better to take a step back and make sure you have learned the fundamentals properly before trying to write a Discord bot. Or *at least* read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: (Hint: where the code says `before = time.monotonic()`, why does it *not* instead just say `before = time.monotonic`? What would go wrong if it were like that instead? Do you see how the same logic applies to using `uptimed`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```py
Embed_De_Ping = disnake.Embed(
        title="Status:",
        description=f">  - Ping da Websocket: **{round(bot.latency * 1000)}**ms \n >  - Ping da Client: **{int(ping)}**ms \n>  - Uptime: **{uptimed}**",
        color=0x2f3136)
```

More specifically, this: `Uptime: **{uptimed}**"`. `uptimed` is a function, and it seems like you forgot to call it. It should be `uptimed()`. Outputting a function without calling it will simply print its memory address.